# Angular template class binding inconsistency

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I've encountered inconsistency in Angular template class binding while using `@angular/material@7.3.0` package.

I've tried to reproduce it in a smaller example but it worked correctly. Unfortunately, the whole codebase connected with this bug is too large.

Now, getting to the point:
I've used `mat-horizontal-stepper` and `mat-step` components. All `mat-step` nodes defined by me are displayed as a `mat-step-header` nodes. `mat-step-header` consists of three divs: ripple, icon, and label.
Its template is defined here: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/7.3.0/src/lib/stepper/step-header.html

```
<div class="mat-step-header-ripple" mat-ripple [matRippleTrigger]="_getHostElement()"></div>
<div class="mat-step-icon-state-{{state}} mat-step-icon" [class.mat-step-icon-selected]="selected">
  ...
</div>
<div class="mat-step-label"
     [class.mat-step-label-active]="active"
     [class.mat-step-label-selected]="selected"
     [class.mat-step-label-error]="state == 'error'">
    ...
</div>
```

The selected step gets `selected` input variable set to `true` and binds its value to `mat-step-icon-selected` and `mat-step-label-selected` classes.
In my application the `selected` variable correctly adds `mat-step-label-selected` class to label `div` but not to the icon `div`. As you can see, the value of the `selected` variable is even reflected in `mat-step-header`:

`ng-reflect-selected="true"`

[image: DevTools screenshot]

I've debugged it down to the `checkAndUpdateView` and `checkAndUpdateNode` methods. The string of classes to be assigned to the icon node were given as `givenValues` variable and it just has not contained `mat-step-icon-selected` class.

Do you have any idea how to track down this bug? Where should I look?

Comment: I can't. The template code pasted here is part of Angular Material, it's not written by me.

Comment: Oh - I see what you mean now. My mistake.